# RegisterClientScriptBlock does not working to close a dialog

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

There's a dialog opened while the code behind processing, but i can't close it from code behind using ScriptManager.

Javascirpt

```
function CloseLoading() {
    document.getElementById('LoadDialog').close();
};
```

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <dialog id="LoadDialog">                       
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                 <tr>
                     <td class="DialogHead">
                         <span>Wait...</span>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td style="padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px; text-align: center;">                                                              
                         <input type="image" ID="LoadIcon" name="imgLoading" src="~/Img/wait.gif" runat="server"/>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </table>                    
         </dialog>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

Code behind

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, typeof(Page), "CloseLoading", "CloseLoading();", true);
```

It's a page that generate a PDF report and save it by pressing a button "export". Before start the processing, the app show a dialog with a loading gif by calling a javascript function. After processing is done, i wanna close this dialog from the code behind, but ScriptManager doesn't work, and the dialog keep opened after the download.

There's no error, just don't close dialog.

Comment: You say there's no errors, but where did you check that? Did you just wait for an exception to occur? Or did you also look at the dev tools in the browser to see if the JS had an error?

Comment: Hi mason. I look at the dev tools and there's no errors listed. If i type mannually the function on console, a message "undefined" is showed, but the dialog closes.

Comment: I also put a breakpoint on the CloseLoading() function and that is never called.